# Group PHP array values based on 2 sub-values

Tags: php, arrays

I have called a JSON array from an API and used json_decode to assign them to a PHP variable.

The array looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "abbr": "XXX",
        "title": "YYY",
        "visible_from_lat": "85",
        "visible_to_lat": "-75",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "abbr": "AAA",
        "title": "BBB",
        "visible_from_lat": "85",
        "visible_to_lat": "-75",
    }
]
```

The array has approx 50 items in total, all of which have a `visible_from_lat` and a `visible_to_lat`. What I need to do is group each items like so:

`visible_from_lat > 0` then assign to variable1

`visible_from_lat < 0` then assign to variable2

Any idea's how I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Hi Alex, I haven't tried anything as I didn't know where to start. I've scouted on here and the php docs but nothing seems to do what I need

Comment: You need to loop the result set with `foreach(){}`, perform the comparison with `if()`, and then make use of the array assignment operator via `$variable1[] = ` or `$variable2[] = ` accordingly. All of these concepts are well below "junior" difficulty so give it even the most basic attempt please.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a basic solution, assuming that in `data.json` file there are your json data:

```
<?php
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));

$resulSetPositive = [];
$resulSetNegative = [];
foreach ($array as $obj) {
     if(isset($obj->visible_from_lat)) {
          if($obj->visible_from_lat > 0) {
               $resulSetPositive[] = $obj; // add obj to positive result set
          }
          else if($obj->visible_from_lat < 0) {
               $resulSetNegative[] = $obj; // add obj to negative result set
          }
     }
}

file_put_contents("negative.json", json_encode($resulSetNegative, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
file_put_contents("positive.json", json_encode($resulSetPositive, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```